# Multiple Flexible Array Member or VLA with Shared Memory and Semaphores

Tags: c, arrays, memory, semaphore, shared-memory

I need to define a struct with two semaphores and three(at the least) or maybe more arrays as members of the struct whose size are variables. Indicative example ( not the right syntax but to give a contextual meaning ; `lr` is typedef for `double`) :

```
int nx = 400,ny = 400,nz = 400;
struct ShMem {
    sem_t   prod;
    sem_t   cons;
    lr      u_x[nx+1][ny+2][nz+2];
    lr      u_y[nx+2][ny+1][nz+2];
    lr      u_z[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2];
};
```

What I need to do is to make the struct ShMem as a shared memory block between two codes aka producer and consumer which compute and read this memory block with the help of the semaphores present in the struct.

Since the array size are variables and will be defined in runtime how do i get a 3 Dimensional variable length array ?

Comment :
If lets say I have `nx`, `ny` and `nz` `#define`d to 400 I follow the following step ( already tested )

```
#define nx (400)
#define ny (400)
#define nz (400)

struct ShMem {
    sem_t   prod;
    sem_t   cons;
    lr      u_x[nx+1][ny+2][nz+2];
    lr      u_y[nx+2][ny+1][nz+2];
    lr      u_z[nx+2][ny+2][nz+2];
};
...
// shared memory allocation
ShmID = shmget(ShmKEY, sizeof(struct Shmem), IPC_CREAT|0666);
...
```

Additional requirement is that for the application I do need those arrays as 3D arrays such that I can index them as `u_x[i][j][k]`, whre `i`, `j`, `k` are indices in the x, y, and z-direction respectively.

Edit after Lundin and Felix solution.

CONSTRAINT - `u_x`, `u_y` and `u_z` needs to be a 3D array/*** pointer which is accessed by `u_x[i][j][k]` -  This can't be changed since this is a legacy code. The arrays need to be set such that the sanctity of the access is maintained. Everywhere in the code it is accessed like that.

Comment: Why not just use pointers to dynamic allocations that can be indexed row, column, layer style, e.g. `u_x[ i + j * cols + k * cols * rows]`?

Comment: @DavidBowling yeah reasonable but just a design decision since the out of the two codes which are using shared mem, one of them is a leagacy code used by many people. So need to have similar semantics for code readability and ease of understanding.

Comment: Do the 3 arrays need to be allocated adjacently or is it enough if they are in shared memory?

Comment: it doesnt matter , they need to be in the shared memory along with the two semaphores. Not a restriction to have them as contiguous memory blocks.

Comment: you ask for something the language just can't do. For readability, why not go with a large dynamic allocation (or FAM at the end of your struct), pointers to the respective starts and some accessor functions or macros for the "3D access"?

Comment: i knew this would come up as a possible solution to define one large memory block (in a FAM perspective) and set the pointers. Could anyone help, i do have a rough idea, but need help in setting the pointers to index three arrays in the i,j,k fashion as 3D array.

Comment: As a struct can have only at most 1 VLA , use `struct ShMem { sem_t   prod;    sem_t   cons;  lr  u[3][nx+1][ny+2][nz+2];
};`

Comment: the VLA you are referring to will be of automatic storage which is not really what I need and moreover the size of these three arrays is much more than the stack limit hence they need to be obtained by the calls of "malloc" or "shmget"( the one i am interested in). As pointed out earlier by @Felix and myself I would then need to set the pointers my self to index each of those arrays. Need help in that as of now !

Answer (score 0):

As already discussed in the comments, C doesn't support something like that. So, you will have to build it yourself. A simple example using a macro to make the "3D access" inside the structure readable could look like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int lr;

struct foo {
    size_t ny;
    size_t nz;
    lr *u_y;
    lr *u_z;
    lr u_x[];
};

#define val(o, a, x, y, z) ((o).a[(o).ny * (o).nz * x + (o).nz * y + z])

struct foo *foo_create(size_t nx, size_t ny, size_t nz)
{
    size_t arrsize = nx * ny * nz;
    struct foo *obj = malloc(sizeof *obj + 3 * arrsize * sizeof *(obj->u_x));

    if (!obj) return 0;
    obj->ny = ny;
    obj->nz = nz;
    obj->u_y = obj->u_x + arrsize;
    obj->u_z = obj->u_y + arrsize;
    return obj;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct foo *myFoo = foo_create(10, 10, 10);

    // set u_y[9][5][2] in *myFoo to 42:
    val(*myFoo, u_y, 9, 5, 2) = 42;

    free(myFoo);
}
```

This uses the single FAM at the end of the struct supported by C, so you can allocate such a struct in a single block. To place it in shared memory, just replace the `malloc()` and use the same calculations for the size.

Comment: the answer very well is correct but it doesn't satisfy the constraint which I have made more explicit.( check the edit of the question )

Comment: @datapanda again, this is impossible. You can't change the language. Sorry to help here ...

Comment: I think I am making it bit confusing and my gut feeling says it is very well doable. Could you have a look at the gist which sets up a 3D matrix. All I need is to make it shareable with race condition protectors using semaphores. [gist](https://gist.github.com/data-panda/88fd918441414110be3be1f31c26100b)

Comment: @datapanda this is in **no way** a 3d array, it's a pointer to pointers to pointers.

Comment: ok so this is I would like to have, maybe the terminology is different but from what I have understood "the pointer to pointer to pointers" has been encoded to make the memory block defined at line no. 9 seem like a 3D array.

Comment: You can only create such a mess with at least 3 individual allocations per "array" (as in your gist) **or** with strict aliasing violations (cause you need different object types). Pick your poison. Or, just use a sane approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build something like this

```
struct ShMem {
  int some_stuff_here;
  size_t x[3];
  size_t y[3];
  size_t z[3];
  int array[];
};
```

And then ignore that the flexible array member type is a plain int array. Instead do something like

```
size_t size = sizeof( int[x1][y1][z1] ) +
              sizeof( int[x2][y2][z2] ) +
              sizeof( int[x3][y3][z3] );

ShMem* shmem = malloc(sizeof *shmem + size);
```

And then when accessing, you use an array pointer type instead of the `int[]`. The code turns a bit nasty to read:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<3; i++)
{
  typedef int(*arr_t)[shmem->y[i]][shmem->z[i]]; // desired array pointer type

  int some_offset = ... // calculate based on previously used x y z
  arr_t arr = (arr_t)shmem->(array + some_offset); // cast to the array pointer type

  for(size_t x=0; x<shmem->x[i]; x++)
  {
    for(size_t y=0; y<shmem->y[i]; y++)
    {
      for(size_t z=0; z<shmem->z[i]; z++)
      {
        arr[x][y][z] = something;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is actually well-defined behavior since the data allocated with malloc doesn't have an effective type until you access it.

"some_offset" in the above example could be a counter variable or something stored inside the struct itself.

Comment: the answer very well is correct but it doesn't satisfy the constraint which I have made more explicit.( check the edit of the question )

Comment: @datapanda This answer doesn't contradict that - it is just that I made the pointers local in the above example, since a pointer to a VLA can't be a member of a struct. Now if your old legacy code does not have VLA and you want to change to VLA, that won't work. The least bad you can do then is to use the above solution together with icky macros. You can't completely change the code and keep it as it was at the same time...